# How can I use package RSelenium in a Shiny app hosted on shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, phantomjs, shinyapps, rselenium

Hello smart people of the internet,

I have written an app in R Shiny that uses the package `RSelenium` (and specifically, its `rsDriver` function). It works fine on my local machine. However, when I try to publish the app to `shinyapps.io` I get an error that I have been able to deduce is being caused by the `library(RSelenium)` command.

Specifically, the following example code, saved as `app.R`, can be successfully published on `shinyapps.io`:

```
library(shiny)
# library(RSelenium)

ui <- fluidPage(title = "This is a shiny app")
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

but it **can't** be published if you remove the commenting out of the second line -- the error message is long and kind of weird, but it appears to be related to phantomJS ("Package phantomjs is not available, but is referred to by another package").

I have tried a few things, such as throwing in `if (!webshot::is_phantomjs_installed()) webshot::install_phantomjs()` at the top but it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There's an open issue for failing RSelenium install - https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/issues/359 , most likely related to development status of `phantomjs` (it's suspended) and availability through Ubuntu 22.04 repositories. I actually did try to deploy RSeleinum + phantomjs app on shinyapps.io,  it failed on `apt-get install -y libssl-dev phantomjs` with `E: Package 'phantomjs' has no installation candidate`.

Comment: Well, that sucks. It seems weird that you would need to use phantomjs when I was using firefox on my local machine. Thanks for investigating! Are there any reasonable workarounds? Like, maybe, use Selenium in Python instead of R's RSelenium? I also see there's a package called `wdman` but I can't figure out what it does